# Subset n number of rows from a dataframe, based on a categorical variable, in R

Tags: r, rows, subset

I have a dataframe (say x) in R:

```
> x
Height  Weight Gender
5     60    m
5     70    m
6     80    m
4     90    m
4     60    m
5     70    f
5     80    f
6     60    f
4     90    f
4     60    f
```

I need an R code that will produce a new dataframe, say y,  that takes the subset of X by Gender and only the first three rows of each gender (1:3) to give the result as follows.

```
>y
Height  Weight Gender
5       60      m
5       70      m
6       80      m
5       70      f
5       80      f
6       60      f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `slice` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
    group_by(Gender) %>% 
    slice(1:3)
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[,.SD[1:3] , Gender]
```

Comment: I tried these two packages. And they both give the results correctly. I liked the format of dplyr the best.

Answer (score 2):

Give `by` a try:

```
do.call(rbind, by(X, X$Gender, head, 3))
```

Comment: this was the fastest way to get the result I needed without having to install packages.